# Hashes vs key scan in REDIS

Tags: redis

My team is using Redis for caching and I want to cache the following structure:

```
inbox --(1 to many)-> folders --(1 to many)-> messages
```

It's just a simple tree with no nesting, and each inbox/folder/message is just a single `int`/`long`. I more often need to get all messages in a single folder, but sometimes also need to get all messages in a whole inbox (all the folders).

For the Redis data structure, I'm considering the following 2:

Storing messages in a list & using `SCAN`

```
key = "inbox_id:folder_id"
value = [message_ids]

fetch_folder(): GET inbox_id:folder_id
fetch_inbox(): SCAN inbox_id:* | GET resulting_ids
// I'm not sure how to do fetch_inbox in just Redis yet, so pipe for now
```

Having a hashmap per inbox

```
inbox_id = hashmap { key = folder_id, value = "message_ids_as_string" }

fetch_folder(): HMGET inbox_id folder_id
fetch_inbox(): HVALS inbox_id
```

Which storage & access pattern would be more performant, assuming 10-100 folders per inbox & 100-10_000 messages per folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sorted set data structure. For example, let's assume the following structure:

###### Inbox 1

| Folder ID | Message ID |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| 5 | 11 |
| 5 | 23 |
| 5 | 35 |
| ... | ... |
| 17 | 113 |
| 17 | 114 |
| ... | ... |

###### Inbox 3

| Folder ID | Message ID |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| 51 | 876 |
| 51 | 877 |
| 51 | 1000 |
| ... | ... |
| 99 | 4095 |
| 99 | 4096 |
| ... | ... |

If the message IDs are unique across all folders in all inboxes, or at least across one inbox, you could create a sorted set for every inbox with the folder IDs as scores and message IDs as members as follows:

#### Add

`ZADD inbox:1 5 11 5 23 5 35 ... 17 113 17 114 ...`

`ZADD inbox:3 51 876 51 877 51 1000 ... 99 4095 99 4096 ...`

where `inbox:1` and `inbox:3` are the keys of the sorted sets, each pair of numbers after them represents the ID of the folder and message respectively.

#### Retrieve

###### To fetch all messages of the folder #99 in the inbox #3:

`ZRANGEBYSCORE inbox:3 99 99` (ZRANGEBYSCORE is deprecated as of Redis version 6.2.0)

`ZRANGE inbox:3 99 99 BYSCORE` (BYSCORE was added in Redis version 6.2.0)

###### To fetch all messages in the inbox #3:

`ZRANGEBYSCORE inbox:3 -inf +inf` or `ZRANGE inbox:3 -inf +inf BYSCORE` (version >= 6.2.0) or `ZRANGE inbox:3 0 -1` (all versions), where `0` and `-1` the first and last indexes of the elements in the sorted set.

In case the message IDs are non-unique across folders, they can be prefixed with the folder ID in order not to rewrite them as the elements have to be unique in a sorted set:

`ZADD inbox:1 5 5:11 5 5:23 5 5:35 ... 17 17:113 17 17:114 ...`

and after retrieving the elements, the IDs should be extracted by removing the prefix in the application.